# ctree() - How to get the list of splitting conditions for each terminal node when the response variable is Categorical variable

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree, party

For reproducing the error and what I intend to get. I have the following example.
Lets say I have a datset : Iris. I am modeling a classification tree using

```
library(party)
ct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris) #here Species is the categorical response variable
print(ct)
plot(ct)
```

[image]

But my question is how do i get the splitting conditions on every node , as well the terminal nodes values?

I found out using

```
library(partykit)
partykit:::.ctree_fit(ct)
```

its easy to find the split conditions. But this takes more than 8 hours for my dataset with maxdepth of tree defined to be 3.

to summarize :

1. I need to find the splitting conditions for a tree using `library(party)`
2. Also find the values in the terminal nodes of the tree. So i can use these values in defining the rules

*Note: My dataset is little complex than the Iris data set. I have the following structure

```
ct <- ctree(Y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 ,  data= MyData,controls = ctree_control(maxdepth = 3))# here Y is factor variable , V1 & V3 is continous , V2 is categorical variable
```

when i do : `where(ct)` i get below error
*Error :

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘where’ for signature ‘"constparty"’
```

Please help me in going further about this problem

Comment: Thanks guys. I should been little careful before posting the question. My bad. But there was two parts to my question. Splitting conditions is found from the above link. How can i find the classification probability values? @42

Comment: Can you show your desired output too please? `where` should work on `party::ctree`, not sure regarding `partykit`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for your quick response. I would like to get something similar to what we have with `partykit` function has.
example : `(pred <- aggregate(predict(ct, type = "prob"),
  list(predict(ct, type = "node")), FUN = mean))
##   Group.1 setosa versicolor  virginica
## 1       2      1 0.00000000 0.00000000
## 2       5      0 0.97826087 0.02173913
## 3       6      0 0.50000000 0.50000000
## 4       7      0 0.02173913 0.97826087` reference [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644908/modifying-terminal-node-in-ctree-partykit-package)

Comment: Does [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171301/interpreting-ctree-partykit-output-in-r/171317#171317) help?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks again! . I looked into this already and modified to rectify my problem, but in vain. What i am looking for is a simple classification probability on the terminal nodes. Ex: Node 6: class1 - 60%,class2 - 40% and for all terminal nodes. Based on this condition , I can only traverse these leaf nodes to find the rules. That is my Idea. Any clue or methods in doing this ? My response variable is Categorical variable , with 2 classes

Comment: As @David Arenburg already pointed out: The `where()` function expects an S4 object as produced by `party::ctree`. The new `partykit::ctree` implementation uses S3 instead and simply uses `predict(..., type = "node")` rather than introducing a new generic function.

Comment: Further links that might be useful for processing the structure of `partykit` trees: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999626/how-to-extract-the-splitting-rules-for-the-terminal-nodes-of-ctree/30000007#30000007 ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443203/ctree-how-to-get-the-list-of-splitting-conditions-for-each-terminal-node/29999993#29999993 ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618490/get-decision-tree-rule-path-pattern-for-every-row-of-predicted-dataset-for-rpart/29638602#29638602

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thanks for your guidance on this. I went through the links you posted. It is useful when I am using a `library(partykit)`. But this is very slow for my data and computes for more than 8 hours on windows machine. Hence i chose `party` over `partykit`. So started all the problems. Any way in doing it using `party`?. `Where()` actually doesn't give the probability of the terminal node classes

Comment: You mentioned that you used `partykit:::.ctree_fit(ct)` which takes 8 hours. I don't understand what you are trying to do with this. In any case, this is not the correct way to fit a `ctree()`.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Since you asked me this , Let me post exactly what i am doing. I am trying to fit a ctree for the data of type: 
Str(testData). data.frame': 410979 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ID   : Factor w/ 503 levels "6862","10022",
 $ Km   : int  52783 50339
 $ MIS  : num  23 19 36 33 4
 $ Class: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1"

I am basically trying to classify the data into class 1 or 0 . My formula of `ctree`: `ct <- ctree(Class ~ Km + MIS + ID ,  data= MyData,controls = ctree_control(maxdepth = 3))# here Class is factor variable , KM & MIS is continous , ID is categorical variable`. Makes sense?

Comment: The ID is surely the problem. Finding the best binary split among 503 levels is computationally very intensive (but this should be the same in `party` and `partykit`). I'm also not sure whether the tree will make sense or be useful for predictions if you have 503 different levels. If these are really individuals and you have repeated measurements then this should probably be handled differently. In any case, this has nothing to do with the original question you asked here and is beyond the scope of this comments section.

Comment: @AchimZeileis thank you for your prompt answer. I will try to find a different method in solving the issue